# Clipboard copy fails

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard

I noticed some time ago that pasting things often pasted some old stuff from clipboard instead of whatever I had just copied. First I thought this has something to do with Excel, but it's apparently a generic problem in Windows or perhaps caused by a background app. Getting CTRL-C working reliably 1st time would reduce ongoing stress by a moderate fraction.

For example, just now I got 2-factor authentication code to my gmail, which is open in Firefox. I change to the relevant tab, highlight the passcode, hit CTRL-C, switch back to the 2FA tab and hit CTRL-V.

Instead of the code I just copied I got back something from an hour ago or more. Going back and copying things again works fine usually.

This happens quite often, I think e.g. highlighting something from a browser when the browser is not active window exhibits this. i.e. I have 2-monitor setup with browser and Word/Excel active. Highlighting a piece of text from an open web page and copying exhibits this issue as the browser windows doesn't actually activate when doing that. But from my example of switching tabs and copying text this seems to be a problem with active window as well.

This is not an isolated thing and a colleague also remarked they've seen this. Is this something Windows 10 has changed or maybe it's something to do with Sophos antivirus or an another TSR program? I'm seeing this on both my home PC and work laptop and they don't have same set of programs running, e.g. home PC doesn't have Sophos, Outlook, Teams, 3CX, Onenote or the VPN client.

Comment: I've got a very silly question to ask, but I would still ask — Have you checked if the keys `ctrl` and `c` are working properly?

Comment: Not sure if it would help, bu you might try a third-party clipboard manager such as CopyQ, Clip Jump, etc.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg That's with three different keyboards so it's probably not a physical thing. Technically it might be caused by e.g. Skype, Google Drive or Spotify as those are running both home and at work laptop.

Comment: @Barleyman what you're talking about is very *wierd*. Usually, softwares don't like to play with system keybindings especially important ones like `Ctrl+C`. Just to be sure, Check your keys, probably you use them too much and therefore the coincidence of problem on 3 systems?